# Changing Nested Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, json, api, dictionary

const projects = [

```
  {

    projectId: 'abc123',

    name: 'Project 1',

    userProjects: [

      {

        userId: 'xyz789',

        projectId: 'abc123',

        user: { userId: 'xyz789', email: 'user1@test.com' },

      },

      {

        userId: 'sdf012',

        projectId: 'abc123',

        user: { userId: 'sdf012', email: 'user2@test.com' },

      },

    ],

  },

  {

    projectId: 'def456',

    name: 'Project 2',

    userProjects: [

      {

        userId: 'xyz789',

        projectId: 'def456',

        user: { userId: 'xyz789', email: 'user1@test.com' },

      },

    ],

  },

];
```

To,
required Output:
[

```
  {

    userId: 'xyz789',

    email: 'user1@test.com',

    projects: [

      { projectId: 'abc123', name: 'Project 1' },

      { projectId: 'def456', name: 'Project 2' },

    ],

  },

];
```

I am stuck on this. What is the best dynamic way to do this?
I was trying to map the array but I am confused with the inner Objects 'user'. Can we directly change this array or we only have to  create a new function?

I was trying to map the array but I am confused with the inner Objects 'user'. Can we directly change this array or we only have to  create a new function?`

Comment: Your first project also had a user `sdf012`, that doesn't show in the desired result. So what is the logic behind this?

Comment: Rather than 'change' the array you should look to build a new one with the format you want. When you change an array while looping over it it can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a reduce with a forEach inside to build an object.  You can use the object to lookup a single user by id, or you can use Object.values to get an array of all users.

```js
const projects = [{
    projectId: 'abc123',
    name: 'Project 1',
    userProjects: [
      {
        userId: 'xyz789',
        projectId: 'abc123',
        user: { userId: 'xyz789', email: 'user1@test.com' },
      },
      {
        userId: 'sdf012',
        projectId: 'abc123',
        user: { userId: 'sdf012', email: 'user2@test.com' },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    projectId: 'def456',
    name: 'Project 2',
    userProjects: [
      {
        userId: 'xyz789',
        projectId: 'def456',
        user: { userId: 'xyz789', email: 'user1@test.com' },
      },
    ],
  },
];

const lookup = projects.reduce((acc, el) => {
  el.userProjects.forEach(up => {
    const id = up.userId;
    
    if (!acc[id]) {
      acc[id] = {
        userId: id,
        email: up.user.email,
        projects: []
      };
    }
      
    acc[id].projects.push({projectId: el.projectId, name: el.name});
  });
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log("single user -->", lookup["xyz789"]);

const output = Object.values(lookup);
console.log("all users -->", output);
```